# Saving a sort by value in views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a table with columns a through f.

I then have a sorting box which sorts columns a through f by weight, location, eye color etc.

Each of weight, location, eye color etc has a starting value of ,for example, None.

Now, you can change the values from None to say, "50-100", "Korea", "Hazel".

If i want to refresh the page, or change the columns that need sorting, how do i keep the sort by values from reverting to None.

Heres a small example of the template code:

```
<form action="" method="get">   
<div class="sort">
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>Sort By</a>
  </li>
</ul>    
<ul> 
  <li id="sample4" class="dropdown4">
    <a href="#">Location    | <span4>World Wide</span4></a>

      <ul><li><a href="#"><input type="radio" id="radio4" name="Location"  value="America"/><label for="radio4">America</label></a>
              <a href="#"><input type="radio" id="radio5" name="Location"  value="Zanzibar"/><label for="radio5">Zanzibar</label></a>
              <a href="#"><input type="radio" id="radio6" name="Location"  value="Aussie"/><label for="radio6">Aussie</label></a>
              <a href="#"><input type="radio" id="radio7" name="Location"  value="Disneyland"/><label for="radio7">Disneyland</label></a>
              <a href="#"><input type="radio" id="radio8" name="Location"  value="Someplace"/><label for="radio8">Someplace</label></a>
              <a href="#"><input type="radio" id="radio9" name="Location"  value="TheOcean"/><label for="radio9">The Ocean</label></a>
      </li></ul>
  </li>
</ul> 
etc.....
```

and a sample snippet of my view

```
arguments = {}
if request.method == 'GET':
    sortlocation = request.POST.getlist('Location')
else:
    pass

if sortlocation == []:
    sortlocation = "World Wide"
else:
    sortlocation = sortlocation[0]             
    pass

if sortlocation is not "World Wide":
    arguments['Location'] = sortlocation
else:
    arguments['Location__isnull'] = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to store state.

The simplest way is to store that information in the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views):

```
request.session['sort'] = 'my_sort_value'
```

To retrieve it in any other view, access it like a dictionary

```
sort = request.session.get('sort', None)
```

Comment: despite reading many tutorials, you always do miss parts, even when re-reading. This was one of those things that i missed. Cheers